# Error message "HTTP 413 Request Entity Too Large" in Android

Tags: android

When I am sending image file using Multipart.Part using POST method and it throwing this error : "retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 413 Request Entity Too Large".

Comment: your file size will be greater than expected file size of api

Comment: same issue is appearing for me! not appearing when calling from postman

Answer (score 1):

By the error its obvious that the file you are sending in request is larger than expected on server. For example in PHP, default MAX file size is 2MB and can be increased if required.

In your current scenario there are 2 options you can do:

1. Compress image to make it below MAX_FILE_SIZE allowed on server
2. Increase the MAX_FILE_SIZE limit on server.

You need to check your requirement and use case of image to choose from these 2 options.

Answer (score 0):

Your request body is larger than the server is configured to allow .Look at this https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/413-request-entity-too-large-error-with-uploading-a-file

Also you can try to compress bitmap before uploading it to server

```
public  Bitmap compressInputImage(Uri inputImageData)
  {
     try
       {
         bitmapInputImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), inputImageData);
         if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() > 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() > 2048)
           {
             dpBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1024, 1280, true);

           }
         else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() > 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() < 2048)
           {
             dpBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1920, 1200, true);
           }
         else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() < 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() > 2048)
           {
             dpBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1024, 1280, true);
            }
         else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() < 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() < 2048)
            {
             dpBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, bitmapInputImage.getWidth(), bitmapInputImage.getHeight(), true);

            }
        } catch (Exception e)  
           {
             dpBitmap = bitmapInputImage;
           }
     return dpBitmap;
   }
```

Comment: But the server max file size is 1MB and i'm send less than 1MB then also getting same issues.