# How to send multipart with images using Retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data

I need to send the same data from the following image (`Postman`)

[image]

I'm using `Retrofit` with `Coroutines`, I tried to use the following snippet to send the request:

```
@POST("ia")
@Multipart
suspend fun getMeasurement(
    @HeaderMap authenticationHeaders: ApiHeaders,
    @Part("userId") userId: RequestBody,
    @Part("sessionId") sessionId: RequestBody,
    @Part file: MultipartBody.Part,
    @Part file2: MultipartBody.Part,
    @Part file3: MultipartBody.Part,
    @Part file4: MultipartBody.Part,
): Response<MeasurementResponse>
```

To create the `MultipartBody.Part`

```
fun createImageRequestBody(imageUri: Uri, fileName: String): MultipartBody.Part? {
        context.contentResolver?.query(imageUri, null, null, null, null)?.use {
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                val picturePath =
                    it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA))

                val requestBody = File(picturePath).asRequestBody("image/jpeg".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                    "file",
                    "${fileName}.jpeg",
                    requestBody
                )
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

to create the other parameters

```
val userId = user.id.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())

val sessionId = session.id.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())
```

I don't know why this results in an error 413 (entity too large) from the server, and it works fine when I try via `Postman`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60034596/19674027

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "HTTP 413 Request Entity Too Large" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034267/error-message-http-413-request-entity-too-large-in-android)

Comment: No, even if I send  small images (about 10kb) the same problem happens, and it doesn't happen with 5mb images in Retrofit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem just by removing HeaderMap from the parameters, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP 413 error response code means that the server is rejecting the request because the payload is too large. In this case, the server is likely rejecting the request because the combined size of all the files being uploaded in the request is too large.

To fix this issue, you can try to reduce the size of the files being uploaded or increase the maximum upload size limit of the server.

Additionally, you can also check the size of each file being uploaded by adding logging statements to your createImageRequestBody function. For example, you can add the following line before returning the MultipartBody.Part:

```
Log.d("TAG", "File size: ${File(picturePath).length()}");
```

This will log the size of each file being uploaded to the console, allowing you to verify that the files are not exceeding the maximum allowed size.

**Edit:**

I just read your comment where you mention that you still receive the issue when sending small files, and sometimes don't receive the issue with a larger files.

If you're experiencing the 413 error even when sending small images (around 10kb), it's possible that the issue is not related to the size of the payload, but rather to the way you're constructing the multipart request.